# R - how to summarise data across pairs?

Tags: r, comparison, summary

I have a dataset with the following structure:

| study | treatment | severity | people_with_pain | sample_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | paracetamol | 5.0 | 12 | 24 |
| 0001 | aspirin | 7.0 | 10 | 20 |
| 0001 | massage | 10.2 | 20 | 21 |
| 0002 | paracetamol | 6.0 | . | . |
| 0002 | aspirin | 6.0 | . | . |
| 0003 | massage | 2.0 | 10 | 25 |
| 0003 | paracetamol | 3.5 | 10 | 25 |

I would like to evaluate `severity` and the proportion of `people_with_pain` within `sample_size` across pairs of different treatments (e.g. paracetamol-aspirin). When the outcome is continuous (`severity`), I am interested in the mean, standard deviation, median and IQR. When the outcome is dichotomous (`people_with_pain/sample_size`), I am interested in the average proportion.

For instance, for the paracetamol-aspirin comparison, `severity` would be 6.0 (average between study 0001, 6.0, and study 0002, 6.0. Study 0003 does not contribute because it compares massage and paracetamol). The average proportion of `people_with_pain` would be 0.5 (study 0001, 22/44. Study 0002 does not contribute as there is no data).

The desired output would as a data.frame per output (e.g. one data.frame for `severity`, one for proportion of `people_with_pain`) with comparisons as rows (e.g. `paracetamol-aspirin`):

| comparison | nstudies | severity_mean | severity_sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paracetamol-aspirin | 2 | 6.0 | 0 |
| paracetamol-massage | 2 | 4.375 | 2.30 |
| aspirin-massage | 0 | NA | NA |

I have managed to build a permutation list of available comparison and exclude those duplicated (e.g. paracetamol-aspirin and aspirin-paracetamol), as well as those not meaningful (e.g. paracetamol-paracetamol), but I am stuck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using tidyverse. I am not completely sure that this is what you want because of some differences between my results and your expected results.
However, to obtain all the combinations of `treatment` I've used a `left_join` of the dataframe with itself, followed by `filter(treatment.x < treatment.y)` which basically eliminates all the treatment pair duplicates.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat |>
  left_join(dat, by = "study") |>
  filter(treatment.x < treatment.y) |>
  unite("treatment", starts_with("treatment"), sep = "-") |>
  group_by(treatment) |>
  summarize({
    severity <- c(severity.x, severity.y)
    people_with_pain <- c(people_with_pain.x, people_with_pain.y)
    sample_size <- c(sample_size.x, sample_size.y)
    data.frame(severity_mean =     mean(severity),
               severity_sd  =        sd(severity),
               severity_median = median(severity),
               severity_IQR =       IQR(severity),
               people_with_pain = sum(people_with_pain)/sum(sample_size),
               nstudies = length(unique(study)))
  })

##>             treatment severity_mean severity_sd severity_median severity_IQR
##> 1     aspirin-massage         8.600   2.2627417            8.60        1.600
##> 2 aspirin-paracetamol         6.000   0.8164966            6.00        0.500
##> 3 massage-paracetamol         5.175   3.5668614            4.25        3.175
##>   people_with_pain nstudies
##> 1        0.7317073        1
##> 2               NA        2
##> 3        0.5473684        2
```